# Prove that the language of squares is not regular using homomorphism

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

If a language like $L$ is regular, then any homomorphism of $L$ is regular too. So, if $h(L)$ is not regular, then we can conclude that $L$ is not regular.

Assume that the language $L=\{yy:y \in \{0,1\}^*\}$ is given.
Can you provide a homomorphism for $L$ like $h$ that $h(L)$ is not regular?

Note : I don't want a simple homomorphism. I want a good homomorphism that $h(L)$ is obviously not regular. So there should be no need to use pumping lemma to prove that $h(L)$ is not regular. But you can use the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Define "obvious". $L$ is well known to be not context-free, so from where I'm standing it's obvious that $L$ is not regular.

Comment: @Raphael target is to find a better way to prove that L is not regular. In the class, our teacher proved this using pumping lemma. But I thought how good it could be if we can find a homomorphism for this language that proving " $h(L)$ is not regular " is simpler than proving " $L$ is not regular "

Comment: This is probably not the best example for this, given that the proof using the Pumping lemma is as immediate as it is. How much better can it get?

Comment: @Raphael The problem of pumping lemma is that we are not sure that the string we chose always works . you chose a string. you partition the word to 3 substrings. and then you pray for this substring to be not regular. i think it's not a systematic way.

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking. I thought a homomorphism is a function. How can a homomorphism be a regular language?  By $h(L)$ do you mean the homomorphic image of $L$?

Comment: @scaaahu yes, i mean the homomorphic image :)

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade True. Only that *there is no systematic way*.

Answer (score 3):

As illustrated by other answer and comments there seems to be no easy way just using morphisms. Still it is a good observation that simple closure properties can be of help.
In your case I would suggest intersection with regular languages as a tool: $L\cap 0^*10^*1 = \{0^n10^n1 \mid n\ge 0\}$ whch some recognize immediately as non-regular.

Alternatively one could include morphisms, inverse morphisms and intersection with regular languages (or, equivalently, finite state transductions). With these regularity preserving operations $L$ can be transformed in to $ \{a^nb^n \mid n\ge 0\}$, mother of all non-regular examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can not prove this using homomorphisms only. There are exactly $2^2=4$ functions $\{0,1\} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$. All larger co-domains can be ignored by restricting the function to its image.

These functions are:

1. $h_0 = \{0 \mapsto 1, 1 \mapsto 1\}$: $h(L) = \{(11)^{n}|n\geq 0 \}$ which is regular
2. $h_1 = \{0 \mapsto 1, 1 \mapsto 0\}$: $h(L) = L$
3. $h_2 = \{0 \mapsto 0, 1 \mapsto 1\}$: $h(L) = L$
4. $h_3 = \{0 \mapsto 0, 1 \mapsto 0\}$: $h(L) = \{(00)^{n}|n\geq 0 \}$ which is regular

So, morphism do improve your prove in any way.

> Can you provide a homomorphism for L like h that h(L) is not regular?

The answer to this question is "yes", because $L$ is not regular and $h_1$ and $h_2$ map $L$ to $L$.

Comment: A homomorphism is allowed to replace a character by a string.

Comment: The definition of homomorphism is not what you wrote sir :) a homomorphism is a function between two alphabets like $ \Sigma_1$ and $ \Sigma_2$. This function should be from $ \Sigma_1$ to $ \Sigma_2^*$.

Comment: Yes, but even morphism $\{0,1\} \rightarrow A^*$ suffer from the same problem:
Cases 1 and 4 remain the regular, same for mappings to the empty word. In cases 1 and 2 you do not change the structural constraints. 
The general approach of using morphisms is to replace some structural constraint by some other (mostly using non-injective mappings). The intention of my answer was to clarify this problem. 
A morphism can not alter the structure of this specific language in a way, that could produce a language different enough to use reasoning that could not have been used on the initial one.